# Filter Records by query on relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I need to get only those users that have role name "Team Leader".

```
user table : role_id
role_table : role_name
```

For example:

```
   $role = Role::where('name', 'Team Leader')->first();
   $team_leaders = User::where('role_id',$role->id)->get();
```

How can I do this directly with query on relationship?

Answer (score 4):

IN User model you should add relation method 'role'

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

   public function role()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
   }

}
```

And then you can do:

```
User::whereHas('role', function ($query) {
    $query->where('role_name', '=', 'Team Leader');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define one to many relationship,
In your Role model,

```
class Role extends Model
{
   public function users()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'role_id');
   }

}
```

in your User Model,

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

   public function role()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
   }

}
```

Now you can get the users list of team leader,

```
$role = Role::where('name', 'Team Leader')->first();
$team_leaders = $role->users;
```

Further more information you can see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is through [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes).

For example:

```
public function scopeTeamLeader($query)
{
    $role = Role::whereName('Team Leader')->first();

    return $query->where('role_id', $role->id);
}
```

To query Users who are then also Team Leaders, you can do something like this

```
User::latest()
    ->TeamLeader()
    ->get();
```

I would also probably define some class constants in my 'App\Role' class. 
For example.

```
class Role 
{
    const TEAM_LEADER = 1; 
}
```

The following could then be cleaned up like this:

```
public function scopeTeamLeader($query)
{
    return $query->where('role_id', Role::TEAM_LEADER);
}
```

Obviously, that's just a personal preference and would not be applicable everywhere, but I think it really improves readability and also reduces your scope by 1 query :)